# Dockerized PHP&SQL instance; could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, sql, docker, pdo

I've been stuck on this problem for the last four hours and I've tried everything I could find on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work.

when visiting the appache server in my container I get greeted with an error: **driver not found**

[image: Error on index.php]

I supsect this is an issue with PDO since the tut I followed used sqlite

In my Dockerfile i did add the PDO extension but to no result?

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
    php-apache-environment:
        container_name: php-apache
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - db
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html/
        ports:
            - 8000:80
    db:
        container_name: db
        image: mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: bitchan
            MYSQL_USER: bit_academy
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: bit_academy
        ports:
            - "9906:3306"
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - '8080:80'
        restart: always
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: db
        depends_on:
            - db
```

and this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql  && docker-php-ext-enable pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

How I connect to the DB on my index.php:

```
$conn = (require "./db/connectdb.php")();

try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM boards");
    $stmt->execute();
    $boards = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT posts.*, b.board_name, b.shorthand FROM posts JOIN boards b on b.id = posts.board_id ORDER BY modified_at DESC LIMIT 5;");
    $stmt->execute();
    $posts = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

and lastely my connectdb.php:

```
<?php
return function () {
    $servername = "db:3306";
    $username = "bit_academy";
    $password = "bit_academy";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=bitchan", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $conn;
}
?>
```

Also my project dir:

[image: view of project directory]

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong you'd make my day! thanks in advance!

Comment: driver not found means pdo_mysql is not installed. pdo_mysql is not installed means RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql didn't run.

Comment: just adding a command to your dockerfile is not enough. you need to rebuild container.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I did indeed rebuild the container, But sadly that hasn't worked for me yet. 

I also don't quite know why it's not installed do I need to change other settings aswell? 

[View of php info PDO section](https://i.imgur.com/W3lHzDT.png)

Comment: @Artemixed  I think it should be just db $servername = "db:3306";

Answer (score 1):

In my case, installing **php8-pdo_mysql** instead of **php-pdo_mysql** module was enough.

I'm using **alpine** image, so I added following line to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add php8-pdo_myql@php
```